# MenusItems of WebDataMenu No Event Fires on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, infragistics

I'm currently using that remote `WebDataMenus` to dynamically add items; through which I access from forms and even trigger events for execution of some function or logic defined.

The problem arises when I want to run my VB.NET code via an `ItemClick` type event, this event is not working properly; or at least I can't get it to work on the server-side (it does not fire), but it works great client-side through JavaScript.

It is worth mentioning that when I click on any items of my menus to run, my VB.NET code gives me a JavaScript error `'__doPostBack' is undefined` - How I can make this work and run the event from my VB.NET code?

PS: To make it work for now, I'm running the VB.NET function from JavaScript through instruction `PageMethods.WebDataMenu2_ItemClick (eventArgs.getItem (). Get_key ());` by setting the `EnablePageMethods = True` property on the `ScriptManager`.

However, this does not allow me to use my other controls from the method that I run, it gives me an initialization error in each of the controls.

1. I add menus and menus items.

   -Code HTML

   ```
   <ig:webdatamenu ID="WebDataMenu2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" 
           Font-Names="Arial Narrow" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="10px" 
           Width="100%"  >
       <GroupSettings Orientation="Horizontal" />
       <ClientEvents ItemClick="WebDataMenu2_ItemClick" />
   </ig:webdatamenu>
   ```

   -VB.NET Code adding Items to Menus

   ```
   ut = New Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls.DataMenuItem
   ut.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("x1").ToString()
   ut.ToolTip = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("x1").ToString()
   ut.Key = "0"
   ut.ImageUrl = "~/ImagesToolBar/employee20.gif"
   WebDataMenu2.Items.Add(ut)


   ut = New Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls.DataMenuItem
   ut.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("x2").ToString()
   ut.ToolTip = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("x2").ToString()
   ut.Key = "1"
   ut.ImageUrl = "~/ImagesToolBar/timecard20.gif"
   WebDataMenu2.Items.Add(ut)
   ```
2. Currently I add a client-side event

   ```
   function WebDataMenu2_ItemClick(sender, eventArgs)
   {
       if (eventArgs.getItem().get_key() != '') {
           alert('test2: ' + eventArgs.getItem().get_key());
       }
   }
   ```
3. VB.NET code here to trigger the event in VB.NET (here fails to execute this method)

   ```
   Protected Sub WebDataMenu2_ItemClick1(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls.DataMenuItemEventArgs) Handles WebDataMenu2.ItemClick


       nodotext = e

       Select Case nodotext
           Case "0"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 1
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "1"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 800
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "2"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 5
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "3"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 6
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "7"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 39
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "8"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 80
               ident = Session("I")
           Case "4"
               Session("IT") = 2
               Session("I") = 100
               Session("RI") = 101
           Case Else
       End Select

       Inicio()
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in a simple sample using the code that you provided and it works as expected for me.  The error about __doPostBack not being defined is would prevent a server side event from firing as that is how asp.net does a post back.

I would recommend that you check the generated html file to verify that this event is defined:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

If the event is defined check for invalid html where maybe you are missing a closing tag or maybe you have other invalid script on the page that is causing the issue.